# Importing XML in cq5.5

Tags: javascript, html, aem

I want to import my data in cq5.5.But the option of content loader is not available in cq5.5.How to import xml in cq5.5.Do we have to create bundles or there is some another way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified if that module is in CQ5.5 or not, but I think the [Sling JCR ContentLoader](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/jcr/contentloader/) should work in CQ if you add it yourself, if it's that module that you mean.

Apart from that, one useful pattern is to drop XML files in a folder, observe that folder via JCR or Sling events and use any suitable XML parser or digester to process it. This gives you full flexibility and using the right parser should allow you to process XML files of arbitrary sizes. The scenario is similar to how Sling's [espblog sample](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/espblog/) detects and processes image files to create thumbnails.

You could also use CQ's workflow engine to detect XML files in specific folders and trigger workflow steps to process/import them, that might give you a better view on things via CQ's workflow console.